# how VAR is determined against many options?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, iqueryable

i have this code :

```
IEnumerable<string> q = customers /*EF entity*/
.Select (c => c.Name.ToUpper())
.OrderBy (n => n)
```

> To select entity, ObjectContext actually create ObjectQuery, which
>   implement IQueryable. The object return from ObjectQuery, is not
>   normal object, but EntityObject

but what if i write :  ( notice the `var`)

```
var q = customers /*EF entity*/
.Select (c => c.Name.ToUpper())
.OrderBy (n => n)
```

it can be determined both to `ienumerable` **or** `iqueryable` :

because  `ObjectQuery` **Also** implements `IEnumerable`...

i dont know if there's any specific info which tell the compiler *"use A and not B. A is more specific..."* ( there must be...i just cant find it)

[image]

any help ? how will it know to use A || B ?

Comment: One easy way to tell what Type var is using in Visual Studio is to hover over the var keyword, and a popup will tell you what type it is. C# in Depth has a good section explaining how type inference works in C#.

Comment: @EricAndres I have resharper which does much better work :)... i just want to understand how the decision is made :).. thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`IQueryable<T>` itself inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), so it's more specific than `IEnumerable<T>`, even though `ObjectQuery<T>` implements both generic interfaces.

Comment: but when the compiler sees `customers /*EF entity*/
.Select (c => c.Name.ToUpper())
.OrderBy (n => n)` ... does it always look in the lower chain of inheritance  towards top ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes. If there are two methods with the same signature, but one takes an interface or type that extends another, the compiler will choose the overload that takes the more specific parameter, unless you explicitly cast the parameter to be less specific (e.g. via the `AsEnumerable()` extension method).

Comment: if 1 methods accepts int and the other accepts object - the decision will be at compile time regarding the COMPILE TIME OF THE TYPE so if i write `int i=3;  doWork(i)` the int version of doWork will be running. and if i send `object i=5; doWork(i)` the object version of doWork will be running .......but here i **dont have** any compile time type...so how does he do it ?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a compile-time type? `var` is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: i meant that its like var i=5;  so i is int ant not object ...int is more specific than object.... same example...no ?